# Why can't I use a functor as the comparator function in btAlignedObjectArray:quicksort?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bulletphysics

This is my code:

```
#include "btScalar.h"
#include "btAlignedAllocator.h"
#include "btAlignedObjectArray.h"

class Comparator
{
    btAlignedObjectArray<int> items;

    // Edit: this member function is to be called from within the comparator
    int myReference()
    {
        return 0;
    }

public:
    Comparator()
    {
        items.push_back(5);
        items.push_back(1);
        items.push_back(3);
        items.push_back(8);     
    }

    int operator()(const int &a, const int &b) const
    {
        return a + myReference() < b;
    }

    void doSort()
    {
        items.quickSort(*this);

        for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
            printf("%d\n", items[i]);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Comparator myClass;

    myClass.doSort();

    printf("done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The error is `No matching function for call to object of type 'const Comparator'`

in lines 345 and 347 in [btAlignedObjectArray.h](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btAlignedObjectArray_8h_source.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `const` to your `operator()`

```
int operator()(const int &a, const int &b) const
//                                         ^^^^^
{
    return a < b;
}
```

Also as you have captured by yourself already, myReference should be const as well

```
int myReference() const
//                ^^^^
```

Comment: I kind of works, sorry I didn't include the whole story, I added the myReference() member function, that needs to be called from within the functor overloaded operator

Comment: The error is that myReference need to be constant, I guess I would have to refactor my code

Comment: basically, all non-static member functions don't intend to modify member should declare as const :)